# Select only white characters in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, textselection

Currently, when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>, Sublime Text 3 will select all spaces (all white characters) from current position until next word *including* this word.

Is there any way (probably yes) to modify ST3's config file or key bindings file to force it to select only spaces (white characters) only, so *excluding* next word? I'm really not comfortable with  default behaviour.

Comment: I would actually like Ctrl-Shift-Left/Right to select upon first click all the tabs/spaces and upon second click the word itself. Never to mix words and spaces. Same goes for punctuation. +1 good question!

Comment: Great and thanks! But, it seems, that we're talking about two different things, because, I'm asking about pure keyboard solution. There's nothing about clicking the mouse in my question! :>

Comment: Apologies, my mistake. EN is not my first language. I want the purely keyboard solution as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default these shortcuts are defined like this:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+right"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "word_ends", "forward": true, "extend": true} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+left"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "words", "forward": false, "extend": true} }
```

The important part is the `by` argument. What the above basically means is that the forward selection should select up to word end (whitespace + next word) and the backwards selection should select up to a word start (white space + beginning of the previous words).

Now to get the result you want you might switch the by for the forwards selection to `words` and for the backwards selection to `word_ends`. That way if you do forward selection only space up to beginning of the next word will be selected and in the case of a backwards selection the whitespace up to the end of previous word will be selected.

To customize it like this, put the following in *Preferences/Keybindings - user* to override the defaults.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+right"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "words", "forward": true, "extend": true} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+left"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "word_ends", "forward": false, "extend": true} }
```

Try it and let me know in the comments if this works for you :)

Comment: What can I say? Works perfectly! :> Thank you!